# Using API in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Can anyone guide me how to use API (like of Twitter, Facebook, Tumblr, etc) in asp.net? I just want something that could teach me to use APIs in my web application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site the other day and it has a gui to help understand the concepts.
http://apigee.com/providers

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20201202214722/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021710-1.aspx
You can search their apis. And also they have a documentation how to use it.